# Hide and Showing 2 Different Element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code like this...

```
<label>Label : </label>
<select name="gs">
    <option value="abc" id="xx" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gs']) && $_POST['gs'] == 'abc' ? 'selected="selected"' : '');?>>ABC</option>
    <option value="cde" id="xx" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gs']) && $_POST['gs'] == 'cde' ? 'selected="selected"' : '');?>>CDE</option>
    <option value="bbg" id="bbg" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gs']) && $_POST['gs'] == 'bbg' ? 'selected="selected"' : '');?>>BBG</option>
</select><br /><br />

<div id="ini">
INI ini INI
</div>

<div id="itu">
ITU itu ITU
</div>
```

Then, what i want to make is..
If iam on codition selected the option BBG, the `<div id="ini">` element will hide then showing the `<div id="itu">` element

So far i try make the code not work at all, here my code like this..

```
    jQuery(function ($){
     $('#bbg').on('click',function(){
         $('#ini').hide();
         $('#itu').show();
     });

     $('#xx').on('click',function(){
         $('#ini').show();
         $('#itu').hide();
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzddqG

```
$('select[name="gs"]').on('change', function () {
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
    if (id === 'bbg') {
        $('#ini').hide();
        $('#itu').show();
    } else {
        $('#ini').show();
        $('#itu').hide();
    }
});
```

You can get the onchange event on a select dropdown. If you really want to get clicks on the option, you should use: `<option onclick="optionClicked()"></option>`

Comment: Put code '$(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');' make this perfect.. beacuse when i load the option option selected will be at the id xx

So #ini element will show then #itu element will hide.. 

Got litle error Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function, then adding 
at the start 'jQuery(function ($){' and closed '});'

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Instead on `click`, you need to use `change`, as that is event for `select` element. Check the below code, they will show/hide based on the selection:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'bbg') {
    $('#ini').hide();
    $('#itu').show();
  } else {
    $('#ini').show();
    $('#itu').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Label : </label>
<select name="gs">
    <option value="abc" id="xx">ABC</option>
    <option value="cde" id="xx">CDE</option>
    <option value="bbg" id="bbg">BBG</option>
</select><br /><br />

<div id="ini">
  INI ini INI
</div>

<div id="itu">
  ITU itu ITU
</div>
```